# Country/city dropdown list in the web-page

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu, web, countries

Where can I find a database of European countries and related cities to implement country/city dropdown list (dynamic) in the web-page?

UPDATE: I´m interested in some database that I can utilize from the javascript or php source code. This is to avoid manual work.

My answer: I have found one more good free resource: http://www.geodatasource.com/world-cities-database

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_cities_by_country

Comment: Thanks, but I´m more interested in the database that I can simply connect from php or javascript. In this case I could avoid hudge manual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MaxMind World Cities](http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities) is a free list that you can download and use in your app (assuming that the license is ok for your purposes). Otherwise they've also got a webservice (though you have to pay for that).

An alternative is [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/).

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe#Political_geography

Wikipedia always works :)

For some reason I thought about capitals only, but I guess you mean all cities.

Take a look at:
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Check out the readme.txt which has more info.
Perhaps cities1000.zip could be used as a base for you. Maybe you need to create a database with the countries you want, and then perhaps filter the list from the link above by ISO-code or something.

The readme also mentions some continent code, so maybe that can be of use?

Comment: So, how do you think I can use this wikipedia link in my source code?:)

Comment: Posted before your update, but I have updated my post now. :) Perhaps you could parse the html from wikipedia, but that would be extremely unreliable (not a serious suggestion) :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx/GetCountries list of countries in xml

Answer (score 0):

http://www.timdavis.com.au/data/

Get an excel for list of country and state.

Answer (score 0):

You need use **Jquery for dynamic ajax dropdown list**. See here php/ajax script -

http://myip.ms/info/cities_sql_database/

Cities table format will be -

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
  `cityID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cityName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `stateID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `countryID` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `language` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cityID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unq` (`countryID`,`stateID`,`cityID`),
  KEY `cityName` (`cityName`),
  KEY `stateID` (`stateID`),
  KEY `countryID` (`countryID`),
  KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
  KEY `longitude` (`longitude`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```